# Ajax wrong request (goes ALSO to another script php ajax script)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, request

I'm having a really weird problem. My jQuery Ajax request is ALSO going to another php ajax script (must go to ajax/sign-in.php and give me an error in ajax/users.php) (without any redirect code) and it's giving me strange errors.

Basically, i have the jQuery Ajax Request:

```
login = function(){
    var data = {
        login    : $('input[name="login"]').val(),
        password   : $('input[name="password"]').val()
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '../ajax/signin.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: data,
        success: function(result){
            addLoading('.signIn button');
            if (result.success){
                //window.location="//aquickgig.com";
                console.log('huehue');
            }else{
                setError(".signIn button", result.error);
            }
            removeLoading('.signIn');
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            alert("Error Status: " + xhr.status + " Thrown Errors: "+thrownError);
        }
    });
}
```

And my Ajax php script:

```
<?php
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 01 Jan 1996 00:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/lib/users.php');
$users = new Users();

isset($_POST['login']) ? $login = $_POST['login'] : $login = null;
isset($_POST['password']) ? $password = $_POST['password'] : $password = null;
$resp = array();

if (strlen($login) == 0 || strlen($password) == 0){
    $resp['error'] = "Please, fill all the fields";
}
elseif (strlen($login) > 50 || strlen($password) > 50){
    $resp['error'] = "Invalid number of characters. Usernames and password cannot be above 50 characters";
}
else{
    $resp['success']  = "something";
}
echo json_encode($resp);
```

?>

When i do the request, the console doesn't give me scripts errors and it does the request. But on the catch, give me the answer: **Error Status 200 Thrown Errors: SintaxeError: Unexpected token <**.

Also, the response from request is **Fatal error:  Class 'Users' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\ajax\users.php on line 8**. I NEVER called the users.php script.

Trying to figure out the problem, i noticed that when i remove or comment the line **include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/lib/users.php');** from sign-in.php, it works perfectly.

I really confused, don't know what's happening. Thank you!

Comment: the include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/lib/users.php'); is a call for the users.php script. 
if you don't need it just remove it and it should be fine also remove this line : $users = new Users();

Comment: It's a call to users.php, but to the LIB (class). The error from message is in AJAX/users.php. Also, i need the include/require of the lib file.

Comment: You appear to have two files calles `users.php` in different folders. This is a recipe for confusion. Are you sure that the version you're loading is the correct one? That is: does it have the correct contents? I'd suggest you find a naming convention that distinguishes classes and other included files from other programs and each other.

Comment: Hi, Hobo. Your answer resolved my question. But after, i tried something. In the lib folders, all the requires was "require_once (file.php);". I changed to "$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/folder/file.php');" and it worked correctly. It seems the system was looking for users.php and he found the first file from ajax folder, that's why it was been included wrongly. I don't know why since there is a script called users.php in the same folder. By the way, your answer is pretty acuratelly, to avoid mistakes. Thanks for the answer!